# gettin error message each time with face book desktop api

Tags: facebook-graph-api, actionscript-3

I am using FacebookGraphAPIDesktop.swc api to create unpublished post.

How can I assign language, location and city parameter with it?

I tried like below, but getting error "(#100) targeting must only contain one or more of countries,regions,cities,locales"

```
_params.access_token = token;
_params.published = 0;      
_params.message = "This is status message for af_ZA 3";                     
_params.targeting="countries=US";                   
FacebookDesktop.api("/202387076493582/feed", messagePosted1, _params,"POST");
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and posting here if anyone needs it :-

We need to pass it as a json string :-

```
var targeting:String = "{'countries':['US','IN']}";

_params.access_token = token;
_params.published = 0;      
_params.message = "This is status message 5";                   
_params.targeting = targeting;                  
FacebookDesktop.api("/202387076493582/feed", messagePosted1, _params,"POST");
```